# Rpm spec option that disallows installation of 32 bit rpm on 64 bit OS

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I would like to create a rpm spec, and add an error when the user tries to install it on a 64 bit OS.
I want to explicitly disallow this action, as I would like the application to run on its native platform, without the need to install compat_libs.

I have tried adding a version check in the %pre section, but it seems that Requires executes before that, and it causes dependency errors.
My code never seems to be executed.

```
Provides: MyRpm
Requires: pciutils, binutils, coreutils, perl

%pre 

uname -p | grep -q "x86_64"
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]  ; then
   echo "You are trying to install a 32 bit rpm on a 64 bit distro"
   exit
fi
```

I would like to know if I am missing something, or if there is a special rpm directive that executes bash code before the Requires step and allows me to customize the output message to the user.

Comment: Have you tried `Requires: pciutils.x86_64`? Like Etan Reisner's answer, I am unsure where you're going with this.

Answer (score 2):

Do those errors not "disallow installation of [your] 32 bit rpm on 64 bit OS"? Or is the issue that you want a friendlier error message?

RPM is going to automatically pick up library requirements/etc. automatically and those will be checked before your `%pre` is called. (There isn't any reason to get to running `%pre` if the transaction is guaranteed to fail for requirements.) I don't believe you can avoid that.

There's only so much protection you can offer to users who aren't paying attention. Presumably your RPM itself has the architecture tag in the filename (as is standard). You can attempt to make the download site more clear what the different RPMs are for as well.

That all being said if your application will run on a 64 bit OS with the right 32 bit libraries then, unless you know of a problem with doing that (as in the application doesn't work correctly or runs significantly slower for some reason), I wouldn't suggest restricting the user's ability to run it on the OS they happen to have available.

Comment: That's right, I would like to display a friendlier message to my users. Due to performance reasons, I would always like to prohibit installation on a non-native platform.  I know about the "Autoreqprov no" option, but that only disables automatic dependency checks. Those in the Requires list are still checked.

Comment: The dependencies on the Requires line shouldn't (I don't think) have architecture attached to them though (but I'd have to check/test to be sure).